# Milliseconds in new Date produces an unexpected result

Tags: javascript, date

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  When I execute this statement:

```
new Date(43 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // ms from Epoch to Jan 1st, 2013
```

I get this:

```
Thu Dec 20 19:00:00 EST 2012
```

I think I'm obviously half asleep, because I'm sure this should be working as expected (obviously not ;) ).

***Update:*** Thanks everyone - yes, I totally forgot about the day loss from leap years.  As a reference for others, you can find more details here:
http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Leap-Years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as expected for that number of milliseconds since midnight UTC on 1/1/1970.

(Why 11 days' difference in addition to the time zone difference? There were 11 leap years between the epoch and 1/1/2013.)

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that.  I see so many examples of converting milliseconds to year, dayOfYear, hour, min, sec, and they were all accepted answers, but I think many people fail to take this into account. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that there aren't 365 days in every year. Additionally it's a good idea to use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) if you're working with dates either way.

Comment: No it's not - why must every small issue like this be solved by some library.  Besides, from what I hear, moment.js is better (and smaller), and updated more regularly. Date.js hasn't been updated since 2010, and the home page is the same since 2008.

Comment: You're right, moment.js is better. Secondly, there is no reason not to use small libraries like moment.js, because it makes the code more redeable and has negligible effect on loading times if taken from a popular cdn.

Comment: I meant I such simple cases such as this, getting a whole library is overkill.  If I were doing a lot of date related work, then yes, it makes sense (as you mentioned in the post).  Abstracting out work to save time is good for business, but it makes for less experienced coders. ;) People should be directed to solve the issues at hand first with solutions, then at the end, and FYI to a library if they don't want to learn, or have the time. :)  In this case, I was directed to look up leap year calculations and learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an explicit constructor? E.g.

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

The Julian constructor is based off the number of days since 01/01/1970

Comment: Simple, because it's not what I need to do. :) I have my reasons.

Comment: Fair enough then. Just be careful with leap years :)

Comment: Yes. I feel stupid now, because I knew about leap years.  I just had a brief brain fog for a bit, confusing it with DST - not realizing at the moment it actually means the loss of a whole day. LOL. :)